# allowing write to one Firebase child when not logged in

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a childnode in my database
Posts --> tapCount.

My default Firebase rules only allow someone to write to a node under 'Posts' when they are signed in. However I need write access to just this one node 'tapCount' even when they are not signed in.

I'm having trouble getting a rule to help me do this. Any thoughts ? Thanks

```
 {
      "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
      "Posts": {
          ".indexOn": ["userId","category"],
          "tapCount": {
              ".read": true,
            ".write": true
            },
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null",
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working the way you expect?  How are you testing this?  The rules simulator in the Firebase console suggests this is OK.

Comment: The rules you have should allow anyone to read from `/Posts` and read/write `/Posts/tapCount`. What isn't working about it?

Comment: I get a permission denied error when I try to write to tapCount: [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038023] runTransactionBlock: at /Posts/-L3f6SHdjKIVW failed: permission_denied                                      
and so I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my permissions. My Posts are nested under a unique id.
My simulator also says read/write access is denied when unauthenticated due to lines 3 and 4.